# Error while executing Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

We get the following error while executing Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport.SQL server firewall rule is configured properly.Container is with Public access.

Error is thrown at this line: Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport -SqlConnectionContext $SqlCtx -StorageContainer $Container -DatabaseName $DbName -BlobName $BlobName -ErrorAction Stop

Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport : An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://management.core.windows.net/*subscriptionid*/services/sqlservers/servers/*sqlservername*/DacOperations/Import. This could be due to the fact that the server 
certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security 
binding between the client and the server.
At C:\Azure\PowerShellScripts\ImportDB.ps1:13 char:1
+ Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport -SqlConnectionContext $SqlCtx -StorageContainer $Co ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport], CommunicationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.SqlDatabase.Database.Cmdlet.StartAzureSqlDatabaseImport

Comment: did you import a cert / publisherfile too or are you using the Windows Account comdlet for login and managing your subscription?

Comment: we import both module and publishsettings path as follows:Import-Module $ModulePath
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile $PublishSettingsPath

Comment: Import-Module $ModulePath
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile $PublishSettingsPath

Comment: Do you have more than one subscription in your publishsettings file?  Is it possible the current subscription doesn't have access to the sql server?